# Notice: Undefined index: access in C:\xampp\htdocs\Course\includes\header.php on line 8?

Tags: php

I am getting an error while running a project using xamp server. The error is Notice: Undefined index: access in C:\xampp\htdocs\Course\includes\header.php on line 8 . 
I include the header.php file here, please help me.

```
<?php
If (!isset($user) && !stristr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'login.php')  
                && !stristr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'add_user.php')
                 && !stristr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'forgotten_password.php')) {   
    $user = $_SESSION['learner'];
    $user->set_profile();
}
If ($_GET['access'] && !stristr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'login.php')) {
tep_set_accessibility($user->id,$_GET['access']);
    $user = $_SESSION['learner'];
    $user->set_profile();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have `access` key in your `$_GET`

Either you pass the value or check it before using it

```
if (isset($_GET['access'])) {
   if ($_GET['access'] && !stristr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'login.php')) {
   tep_set_accessibility($user->id,$_GET['access']);
    $user = $_SESSION['learner'];
    $user->set_profile();
  }
}
```

Comment: its right...thank you friend..

Answer (score 3):

you need to check if $_GET['access']  has been set:

```
if (isset($_GET['access'])) {

}
```